# Android - Start camera with specific save location

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want to start the camera app via an intent, and save the image inside of my application directory so that it does not show up in the gallery/the photo is private.

Here is my code:

```
File dir= this.getDir("dirname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File file= new File(dir, "filename");                               
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, dir);         
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST_IMAGE);
```

I get a an error under `getDir`.

```
The method getDir(String, int) is undefined
```

Would this process allow for the image to be saved secretly as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to start the camera app via an intent, and save the image inside of my application directory so that it does not show up in the gallery/the photo is private.

That's not possible by default, as the camera app does not have rights to write to your directory.

> I get a an error under getDir

Then `this` is not [a `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Also note that the only prayer you have of this working would require you to make this directory `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`, and that has security implications.

Comment: "not possible by default" Does that mean that there is a way to allow it to write to my directory? Also, could you expand on "MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE" having security implications?

Comment: @EGHDK: "Does that mean that there is a way to allow it to write to my directory?" -- you would have to create the directory as `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` instead of `MODE_PRIVATE`, and hope that this is sufficient. I have never tried this. "Also, could you expand on "MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE" having security implications?" -- any app can read or write from this directory with impunity. They don't even nee a permission like `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. And so you have to be very very careful what you put in there.

Comment: If the user is rooted... then they can access all of the directories anyway... correct?

Comment: @EGHDK: A user of a rooted device *can* run apps as root, and then those apps can access anything. Users of rooted devices do not normally run *all* apps as root. However, *any* app on *any* device can read and write a `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` directory. Root is not required.

Comment: If I set my folder to `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` will the gallery show my folder? Or better yet... how does the gallery know which folders to show?

Comment: @EGHDK: "how does the gallery know which folders to show?" -- it shows whatever the `MediaStore` has indexed, which usually is just external storage. I have never tried using `MediaScannerConnection` to trigger indexing of a world-readable file on internal storage, as I would never create a world-readable file on internal storage.

Comment: Okay... last question then "I would never create a world-readable file on internal storage." Why would you not do that?

Comment: @EGHDK: Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE